# Add a comma after each list items but only if there are more than 1 item in the list

Tags: php, loops, foreach, split

I have a list of tags that I'm using to filter projects inside a data attribute.

I used split() for my array, however I need to add a comma as a separator if there is more than one item in the list. Ideally this is how I would like it to work.

```
// Senario 1 – Single item
<a href="#" data-tag="projects">Project Title</a>

// Senario 2 – More than 1 item
<a href="#" data-tag="product,commercial,housing">Project Title</a>
```

My current code:

```
<?php foreach($project->tags()->split(',') as $tag): ?>
   <a href="#" data-tag="<?php echo $tag; ?>">Project</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm just not sure how to check if I've completed the loop after first.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `implode` function. [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
<a href="#" data-tag="<?php echo implode(',', $project->tags()) ?>">Project</a>
```

Comment: Very short and much neater way than mine. Totally forgot about the implode function! +1

Comment: just need an if statement to check the length of the project  tags array, if the length is 1 then no need for implode... just print the tag as it is else use implode

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Even if there is only one value in array the implode will work. It will just output the value. I think no need if condition

Answer (score 0):

Build your string first before adding it into your anchor:

```
<?php
$result = '';
foreach($project->tags()->split(',') as $tag) {

     $result .= sprintf('%s,', $tag);     
}
//Will remove the last character of the string.
$result = substr($result, 0, -1);
?>

<a href="#" data-tag="<?php echo $result; ?>">Project</a>';
```